# SQL query: add missing Days in query result

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm not a sql-pro.

I have make this query:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID,5,2) as INT), Sum(FEHLER.FehlerSumme)
FROM BLA.FEHLER FEHLER
WHERE (FEHLER.MAE=7) AND (FEHLER.LosID>16100100)
GROUP BY CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID,5,2) as INT)
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID,5,2) as INT)
```

The result is for example:

```
(Column 1 = Day | Column 2 = Sum defective parts)
2 | 18
3 | 7
9 | 5
```

But I need somthing like this:

```
1 | (0 oder NULL)
2 | 18
3 | 7
4 |
5 |
6 |
7 |
8 |
9 | 5
...
31 |
```

So I want join the query on top with this but I was not successful.

`SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=31`

Is it a good idea to solve the problem with this subquery or have you better ideas?
(Query in Excel, Oracle-SQL-Server)

Thanks for help

Comment: So which one, Excel **or** SQL Server **or** Oracle?

Comment: Oracle and "SQL Server" are two very different DBMS products.

Comment: Its in Excel. SQL query to a Oracle-Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Oracle

```
select      
    r.n, t."Sum defective parts"
from                   
   (SELECT LEVEL as n 
    FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31) r
left join  
    (SELECT 
         CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID, 5, 2) as INT) as "Day", 
         Sum(FEHLER.FehlerSumme) as "Sum defective parts"
     FROM 
         BLA.FEHLER FEHLER
     WHERE 
         (FEHLER.MAE = 7) AND (FEHLER.LosID > 16100100)
     GROUP BY 
         CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID, 5, 2) as INT)) t ON t."Day" = r.n
 ORDER BY   
     r.n;
```

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks. I will try it tomorrow!

Comment: @MrBlue  ...and if you prefer 0 instead of NULL, you can do that easily in the second line of code; instead of `r.n` you can select `coalesce(r.n, 0)`. `COALESCE` returns its first argument, unless the first argument is NULL in which case it returns the second argument. (In Oracle that is also often written as `nvl(r.n, 0)`.)

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have data in the table for each day, but the `WHERE` clause is filtering out certain day, then you can fix this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(f.LosID, 5, 2) as INT),
       Sum(case when f.MAE = 7 AND f.LosID > 16100100
                then FEHLER.FehlerSumme
           end)
FROM BLA.FEHLER f
GROUP BY CAST(SUBSTR(f.LosID, 5, 2) as INT)
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(FEHLER.LosID, 5, 2) as INT);
```

This will not work in all cases, but in many cases it offers a simple solution to this type of problem.